# Match mutliple columns in CSV; copy value from one CSV to other if equal

Tags: python, csv

I have two files (csv1 and csv2) which contain overlapping information; where there are matches, I want to copy values from a column from csv2 to csv1.

csv1 is in the form of:

```
empid, name, org, division, title, country, topic, time-on-topic
```

csv2 kind of an aggregated version of csv1 but in the form  of:

```
org, country, topic, rating
```

My desired result, new_csv, is:

```
empid, name, org, division, title, country, topic, time-on-topic, rating
```

Basically, for any matches of 'country' and 'topic' between csv1 and csv2, copy the associated 'rating' back to csv1 structure into a new file, csv3.  I'm embarrassed to admit that I've spent lots of time searching around the message board on using dictionaries, tuples, and lists and so far I can only get it to work if I only use one column as the key. Can 2 columns serve as the key? Or am I asking the wrong question?

This is what I've been doing so far but with 'empid' as the key:

```
with open('csv1.csv', 'r') as f:
    first = {rows[0]: rows[1:] for rows in list(csv.reader(f))}

with open('csv2.csv', 'r') as f:
    for row in csv.reader(f):
        if row[0] in first: # row[0] = url
            first[row[0]].append(row[2])

merged = [(k,) + tuple(v) for k, v in first.items()]

with open('output.csv', 'w') as f:
    csv.writer(f).writerows(merged)
```

I think the crux of my problem is using two columns as keys, but I'm not sure...and I can see that in some instances I might use multiple columns as keys. Should I be somehow concatenating the columns to create keys?

Comment: Consider importing csvs into datasets (Stata/SAS, R dataframes, even Python pandas dataframes) or databases (SQLite/MS Access are file-level dbms) and merge/join the two for new assigned columns. No loops needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per suggestion on using dataframes, I ended up implementing the following script based on pd.merge().

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('csv1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('csv2.csv')
result = pd.merge(df1, df2, on = ['empid', 'name', 'org', 'division', 'title', 'country', 'topic', 'time-on-topic'], how = 'right')
result.to_csv("output.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is some code that should do what you wanted:

```
COUNTRY_CSV1, TOPIC_CSV = 5, 6

with open('csv1.csv', 'r') as f:
    first = {(rows[COUNTRY_CSV1], rows[TOPIC_CSV1]): 
             rows for rows in list(csv.reader(f))}

COUNTRY_CSV2, TOPIC_CSV2, RATING_CSV2 = 1, 2, 3
with open('csv2.csv', 'r') as f:
    for row in csv.reader(f):
        key = row[COUNTRY_CSV2], row[TOPIC_CSV2]
        first.get(key, []).append(row[RATING_CSV2]

with open('output.csv', 'w') as f:
    csv.writer(f).writerows(first.values())
```

The main logical change from the question is that here we use a two-tuple as a key (with the specific two-tuple nbeing the country, topic, as requested).

But there are also a bunch of other cleanups -- instead of splitting and then remerging the row, we keep the "key" parts in the value as well. This redundancy makes the writing-out code much simpler.

The indices have been changed to constants to be clearer about which fields are wanted. Finally, the "if" statement has been replaced with a get method call, which returns a new list. This seems like spurious overhead, but it is unlikely this is slower (and might even be faster -- performance in Python is weird) but is probably less error-prone.

Comment: Thank you! I understand conceptually and the fault is probably mine because I'm such a newbie, when i try to run the script, I get an invalid syntax error on line 7    "rows for rows in list(csv.reader(f))....." any idea why?